# how to use localstorage in next js outside of components

Tags: typescript, axios, local-storage, next.js13, next-auth

the main problem with localStorage is with my axios interceptors

```
import axios from "axios";

const API_URL = "http://localhost:5000";

const $api = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,
  baseURL: API_URL,
});

$api.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem(
    "access_token",
  )}`;
  return config;
});

export default $api;
```

I'm trying to do authorization using next -auth and without my custom $api axios with interceptors it works quite well, but it annoys me that when I want to change axios.post(...) to $api.post(...), then the autorize function stops working

```
async authorize(credetials) {
        if (!credetials?.email || !credetials?.password) {
          return null;
        }
        const { email, password } = credetials;

        try {
          const res = await $api.post("/auth/login", {
            email,
            password,
          });

          if (res.data) {
            return res.data;
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
          return null;
        }
      },
```

doesn't work (with $api)

```
async authorize(credetials) {
        if (!credetials?.email || !credetials?.password) {
          return null;
        }
        const { email, password } = credetials;

        try {
          const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/auth/login", {
            email,
            password,
          });

          if (res.data) {
            return res.data;
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
          return null;
        }
      },
```

works (with default axios)

I asked ChatGPT, but since I have version 3.5 and it doesn’t understand exactly what I want, he suggested doing it like this

```
$api.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem(
      "access_token",
    )}`;
  }
  return config;
});
```

add window type check
but it didn't change anything

How can I make sure that the token that arrives is recorded in localStorage?

Comment: What does "stops working" mean? Does it throw something?